# Defining recursive algebraic data types in XML XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, algebraic-data-types

Imagine I have a recursive [algebraic data type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type) like this (Haskell syntax):

```
data Expr = Zero
          | One
          | Add Expr Expr
          | Mul Expr Expr
```

I'd like to represent this in XML, and I'd like an XSD schema for it.

I have figured out how to achieve this syntax:

```
<Expr>
  <Add>
    <Expr>
      <Zero/>
    </Expr>
    <Expr>
      <Mul>
        <Expr>
          <One/>
        </Expr>
        <Expr>
          <Add>
            <Expr>
              <One/>
            </Expr>
            <Expr>
              <One/>
            </Expr>
          </Add>
        </Expr>
      </Mul>
    </Expr>
  </Add>
</Expr>
```

with this schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="Expr">
  <xs:choice minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Zero" type="Zero" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="One" type="One" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Add" type="Add" />
    <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Mul" type="Mul" />
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Zero">
  <xs:sequence>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="One">
  <xs:sequence>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Add">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" name="Expr" type="Expr" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="Mul">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" name="Expr" type="Expr" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

But what I really want is this syntax:

```
<Add>
  <Zero/>
  <Mul>
    <One/>
    <Add>
      <One/>
      <One/>
    </Add>
  </Mul>
</Add>
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use substitution groups:

```
  <xs:element name="Expr" abstract="true"/>

  <xs:element name="Zero" substitutionGroup="Expr">
    <xs:complexType/>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="One" substitutionGroup="Expr">
    <xs:complexType/>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Add" substitutionGroup="Expr">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" ref="Expr" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:element name="Mul" substitutionGroup="Expr">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2" ref="Expr" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for that! I'm kind of an accidental XSD author, so all I know is what I've spotted in Intellisense. :)

Comment: Now the next question is, can I use substitution groups with the XmlSerializer and inheritance (and some attribute letting it know what derived classes I care about), or do I have to implement IXmlSerializable myself?

Comment: In answer to my own question, yes. This page is useful: http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/problems-with-using-xsdexe-to-generate-net-classes-from-the-fpml-xsd-schema-introduction-to-using-fpml-with-net-tools-part-4/