# Polymorphic interfaces in WCF or ASMX SOAP web services

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services

I would like to represent polymorphic data in a dotNET SOAP web service implemented either in WCF or ASMX in such a way that the schema properly reflects my intentions.

In particular I am interested in the closed polymorphism (AKA sum type AKA tagged union AKA algebraic data type...) required to express structured data such as JSON.

This is a question that has been asked in different forms many times. However answers often claim that it is impossible even in principle to represent polymorphism in a messaging protocol. e.g.

[WCF MessageContract Inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321278/wcf-messagecontract-inheritance/1321412)

Of course allowing open polymorphism, that is to say allowing `X` to be of any type which implements interface `I`, raises non-trivial design questions. However closed polymorphism (`X` may be any of the types `T1`, `T2`, `T3`) is not a difficult thing to design a protocol for, indeed http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema has `substitutionGroup` which does exactly this job. See:

[Defining recursive algebraic data types in XML XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511079/defining-recursive-algebraic-data-types-in-xml-xsd)

Everything I have read until now suggests that neither WCF nor ASMX are able to generate schemas with  `substitutionGroup` or any other means of properly expressing polymorphism. Instead I am left with listing the concrete types in a `KnownTypes` property on the data contract and hope for the best.

If that really is the best we can do, this seems like a failure to express a pretty basic interface concept and I am sure the good folks at Microsoft have a very good excuse. I would be grateful if anyone can enlighten me as to the reason.

Comment: `X may be any of the types T1, T2, T3` - That's what `KnownType` is for in WCF

Comment: `<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="theCatalog" nillable="true" type="q4:ArrayOfKeyValueOfanyTypeanyType" xmlns:q4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>`